# Qubes Post-Install Problem

Tags: linux, fedora, virtual-machine, qubes

I already installed qubes it's booting to gui but i can't start any domain i keep getting this error.
i have amd 5600x with amd-v enabled. i think it got something to do with csm being enabled which i believe will disable some virtualization feature but if i disable csm i can't boot into qube or reinstall the os

this happens in second phase of installtion (after first reboot configuration)
[image]

sudo cat `/var/log/libvirt/libxl/libxl-driver.log`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you have CPU Virtualization enabled, amd-v. What you don't say is if you have IOMMU support enabled. And from this AMD processor guide, I don't think the 5600x has IOMMU support. I don't see it in the feature list.

[AMD Processor Specifications](https://www.amd.com/en/products/specifications/processors/7746%2C7696%2C2571%2C2586%2C2601%2C2611%2C3376%2C9221%2C2481%2C11776%2C1736%2C1896%2C2466%2C176%2C146%2C116)

Qubes-OS is heavy on the virtualization requirements.

You can test whether this is the case by converting sys-usb and sys-net to Para Virtualization (PV). Then see if sys-net comes up and if you are able to launch other VMs.

From:

https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/installation-troubleshooting/

1. Change the virtualization mode of sys-net and sys-usb to “PV”
2. Add qubes.enable_insecure_pv_passthrough to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX in /etc/default/grub
3. Run sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/qubes/grub.cfg
4. Reboot

You can change the virtualization mode by bringing the Qubes Manager from Qubes Tools. Right click on the sys-net VM. Chose Settings, then the Advanced tab, then in the dialog there is Virtualization, change it from HVM to PV.

If you are using a non-UEFI BIOS, your grub2 mkconfig command line will be "sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg".